# Postgresql Request a Table that shows if connection is Kerberos or NTLM

Tags: postgresql

I am in a windows server to windows server environment and converting from SQL Server and have SSAPI "working" but have no way from Postgresql (13) to confirm that the authentication "scheme" used was Kerberos (much preferred security wise) or if it fell back to NTLM.

In SQL Server there is a view dm_exec_connections that has an auth_scheme column that shows this.  I would like to know if I can query this from postgresql.   Should pg_stat_gssapi show this and if so what I would I see if Kerberos vs NTLM?  I would to request this in future versions.

Comment: If you disable NTLM in the domain, you won't have to worry about NTLM connections to begin with. It's not *Postgres* that authenticates the client, it's the domain

Comment: Checking `dm_exec_connections` in SQL Server isn't helpful, as the connection is *already* made. It's an indirect way of determining whether NTLM is disabled at best.

Comment: Sorry, @PanagiotisKanavos , our group is not in control of the domain so NTLM will remain a possiblity.  I will have someone check this from Domain Controller events, but even after that a dm_exec_connections like capability would be used if available.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/klist

Thank you
https://serverfault.com/questions/682027/check-primary-authentication-protocol-for-active-directory-ntlm-or-kerberos

2 options were immediately useful from an admin command prompt - klist sessions shows all my connections are kerberos
and klist get host/servername shows the kerberos ticket process steps (ok not useful but interesting how it works)